# Alternatives to std::vector due to reallocation that invalidates pointers to elements

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2015, stdvector

this might be a newb question (i am) but i've searched as much as i could to find a solution to the following problem

I have the following scenario (heavily distilled of course):

```
class Container
{
std::vector<Object> obj;
};

class Pointers
{
std::vector<Object*> obj_ptr;
};
```

I have a routine that pushes back an element of type Object to the vector **obj** in Container then pushes back the pointer to that same element to **obj_ptr**.

the overall idea is that **obj_ptr[i]** == **&obj[i]** throughout the life of the program.

The problem I run into is that whenever the capacity of **obj** needs to increase all the pointers are invalidated, making the **obj_ptr** completely useless. I have tried both obj.reserve() using the maximum expected size (around 10^7) and initializing the vector with that same size. Problem still persists.

Not sure if it's important, but I'm using VS 2015 Com.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a design problem on your side / XY problem. Why would you ever want to have such a second vector in the first place? E.g if you need a way to iterate over the pointers of yonder objects, implement a custom iterator. If want to implement an interface which exposes the objects as pointer, directly access the vector in the implementation of your interface.

Comment: Hi Sebastian. It was a distilled version of the following problem

The container in this case is a **mesh** that has **points**,  **edges**, and **faces**

basically, every point, edge and face need to know which **mesh** it belongs to, and  which are its adjacent **point**, **edge**, **face** elements, so that some sort of algorithm can be applied to modify the geometry.

so to avoid duplicates, only the **mesh** contains **vector<point>>**, **vector<edge>**, and **vector<face>**. for each of the other types the adjacency lists are stored in vector of pointers.

Comment: Simply use indices instead of pointers and your problem vanishes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The common alternative is using [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) like

```
class Container {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> obj;
};
```

or

```
class Container {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> obj;
};
```

Depends on your use case (semantically).

Comment: Um, no, even a smart pointer isn't smart to know that the original vector was reallocated.

Comment: @PeteBecker: But `obj[i]->get() == obj_ptr[i]` will still be true after reallocation. I think that was the point of the answer.

Comment: Thanks. **shared_ptr<Object>** works nicely. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, I see: you put a smart pointer into the other container. Sigh. Too complicated for me...

Comment: Sorry about the stupid edit; I had to do that to unlock the question so I could cancel my downvote.

Answer (score 4):

[Boost stable vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.stable_vector) is designed for this. It is a vector (access in O(1), etc.) which does not invalidate its values. It is complying to the standard C++ container API/semantic.

It is similar to a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` but hides the smart pointer from you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The major drawback is that it is not standard.

Comment: @AdlA, well its not in the standard library, yes. If you don't want to depend on thirs party libs, you can roll you own implementation by wrapping std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>.

Comment: wrapping `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>` is an interesting option, simply for the option of making it slightly less verbose. Also, i only need to add and read elements (no popping, deleting) so it might be "safer". cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::list` or `std::forward_list` in `Container`, so that the pointers are not invalidated.

```
class Container
{
std::forward_list<Object> obj;
};

class Pointers
{
std::vector<Object*> obj_ptr;
};
```

---

Pay attention to the process of deleting elements from `obj`, though. Deleting an element from `obj` *does* invalidate the corresponding pointer in `obj_ptr`.

Comment: of course, a lot of care must still be taken this way

Comment: @M.M: Well... yes :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of choices

- Use a data structure like `std::list` or `std::deque` where adding elements does not invalidate pointers to previsouly added elements.
- keep indexes instead of pointers in your second array
- have only vectors of pointers -- perhaps a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>` for the first array and `std::vector<Object *>` for the others, or perhaps `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>>` for all the arrays.

Which makes the most sense depends on what it is you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, all those suggestions seem to be valid. In my case, I think the best is the `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>>`. Cheers!