# When passing a std::map to a thread I am getting inconsistent behavior

Tags: c++, multithreading, dictionary, reference, c++17

In the [linked](https://gist.github.com/surajRathi/4a1def6006ceef6f4e7364e5047aebf3) code, I am trying to pass an std::map to the thread as a reference (using std::ref). However, sometimes when the map is accessed my the thread it is empty.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: You may have a race on `options` vector. You give the worker thread a reference to the vector's element, then add to the vector - this may cause the vector to reallocate its storage, which invalidates all pointers, references and iterators into it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I did not expect the vector a stored element. Is there any other size flexible stl containers which wont do this? Do i need to pass pointers?

Comment: `std::deque` doesn't invalidate pointers or references when elements are added at either end. Or, you could just pass the map to the thread by value, so it gets its own copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::vector` invalidates pointers or references when elements are added.

I ended up using a std::vector of std::unique_pointers to store the map.

Use a `std::deque` or pass by value.

As commented by  Igor Tandetnik.

Also refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35687252/1515394)